# Пользовательский интерфейс текстуры и прочие украшательства

Tags: android

Версткой под андроид почти не занимался, интересует наиболее правильный подход к этому делу. Не хочется плодить велосипедов и откровенный быдлокод - поэтому хотелось бы услышать советы от профессионалов: чего следует избегать, чем пользоваться и любые другие советы.

Answer (score 2):

Как делать интерфейс, описано [здесь](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

Как не стоит делать интерфейс - [здесь](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/).

Замечу, что в большинстве случаев разноцветный интерфейс с нестандартными элементами и в нестандартных местах - плохое решение. Лучше поднажать функционал и предсказуемость.

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит делать интерфейс с абсолютным позиционированием, это первый совет)
Используй LL или TL для размещения элементов, это второй совет)
Следи за наложением элементов, чтобы не вышел слоенный пирог.
В ходе работы проверяй что вышло на эмуляторе Anroid